# Draw CSS transformation (Scale, Rotate, Left, Right) on Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm taking photos from user's web camera and drawing it on Canvas. I have built video controls using CSS such as zooming video, rotating it, moving left/right. It's applying on live stream, but When I take photos and draw on Canvas these features (rotate, zoom) don't apply.
I know, because I haven't altered Canvas that's why it isn't applying.

So, any idea how can I draw [rotated, zoomed, moved left/right] on canvas using that same CSS code. (or may be code specific to Canvas context).

Comment: Take a look at html2canvas script https://html2canvas.hertzen.com .

Comment: Hi @DariuszSikorski, not big fan of adding many scripts.libraries. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Transformation made easy.**

Unfortunately the given answer fails to describe the correct usage of scale, translate, and rotate functions. These function multiply the existing transformation and thus the results are relative rather than absolute. For example from the default transformation

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // set the transformation to the default identity matrix
ctx.scale(2, 2);  // scale the transform. Objects are now drawn 2 time larger
ctx.scale(2, 2);  // This is applied to the existing scale
                  // objects are now draw 4 times as large not 2 times
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2); // rotate the transformation 90 deg clockwise
                         // objects are drawn with the x axis down the screen
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2); // Rotate a further 90 deg clockwise
                         // objects are drawn with the x axis from right to left
                         // and the y axis moves up
```

The `ctx.translate(x, y)` function is also relative and is more complicated to work out as the coordinates that you provide are transformed by the existing transformation. So if applied after the above code giving a translation of 100 by 100 would first scale and rotate by 4 and 180 degrees. The resulted position would be at the canvas coordinates x:-400 and y:-400. To translate to the desired coordinates (100, 100) would require first applying the inverse transformation, that would result in `ctx.translate(-25, -25)`

Because there is no way to know with certainty the current transformation it is very difficult to compute the inverse transformation and apply that so you can work in canvas coordinates.

**setTransform**

Not all is lost the canvas 2D API provides a function `ctx.setTransform()` which replaces the current transformation with a new one. It is not relative but absolute. This allows you to know with certainty the current transformation and greatly simplifies the process of transforming an image (or anything being drawn)

**A general purpose function.**

To rotate zoom and position an image here is a general purpose function to do that for you.

**The Arguments**

- **ctx**: The 2D canvas context to draw to.
- **image**: The Image to be drawn.
- **x, y**:  The absolute canvas coordinates to place the center
  coordinates at, measured in pixels from the top left of the canvas.
- **centerX, centerY**: The coordinates of the image origin in pixels relative to the image coordinated. If the image is 100 by 100 then setting centerX, centerY to 50,50 will scale and rotate around the center of the image and draw that center at the coordinates given by the arguments x and y. if centerX, centerY are given as 0,0 then the image is rotated and scaled around the top left corner.
- **scale**: The scale to draw the image. A value of 1 is no scale, 2 is
  twice as big 0.5 is half the size. Negative numbers revers the image
  in the x and y directions
- **rotate**: The amount of rotation given in radians with 0 being no
  rotation and then in 90Deg steps clockwise are `Math.PI / 2`,
  `Math.PI`, `Math.PI * 1.5`, and back to the start `Math.PI * 2`

**What it does**

The function sets the absolute transformation with the desired scale and translation. The applies the rotation to that transform, then draws the image offset to place the centerX, centerY at the desired coordinates. Finally the function set the transformation back to the default. This is strictly not needed if you use the function or setTransform for all transformations but I have added it to not mess up 80% of existing code that would rely on the default transform being current.

**The Function source code.**

```
function drawImage(ctx, image, x, y, centerX, centerY, scale, rotate){
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);  // resets transform and 
                                                 // set scale and position
    ctx.rotate(rotate);  // apply the rotation to the above transformation
    ctx.drawImage(image, -centerX, -centerY);  // draw the image offset to its center
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore the transformation to default.
}
```

Or the simpler version that does not do the unneeded reset to the default transform

```
function drawImage(ctx, image, x, y, centerX, centerY, scale, rotate){
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);  // resets transform and 
                                                 // set scale and position
    ctx.rotate(rotate);  // apply the rotation to the above transformation
    ctx.drawImage(image, -centerX, -centerY);  // draw the image offset to its center
}
```

Or this that assumes you always use the image center

```
function drawImageCentered(ctx, image, x, y, scale, rotate){
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);  // resets transform and 
                                                 // set scale and position
    ctx.rotate(rotate);  // apply the rotation to the above transformation
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);  // draw the image offset to its center
}
```

**Usage**

```
// image; is a 200 by 200 pixel image
// ctx; is the canvas 2D context
// canvas; is the canvas element

// call the function
drawImage(
    ctx,          // the context
    image,        // the image to draw
    canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2,  //draw it at the center of the canvas
    image.width / 2, image.height / 2,    // at the image center
    2,            // scale to twice its size
    Math.PI / 4   // and rotated clockwise 45 deg
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via CSS, but with some javascript when drawing to the canvas. For zoom, you'll need to handle it semi-manually, using the parameters to `drawImage` on the context from `canvas.getContext()`. Basically parameters 2-5 are the (in order), x, y, width and height of area from which you are extracting the image and parameters 6-9 are the same for how it gets put into the image.

So for example, if your base image is 2000x2000 and you are imaging it into a canvas which is 1000x1000:

The following will just draw the whole image into the smaller image.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,2000,2000,0,0,1000,1000);
```

While this will draw the middle 1000x1000 of the base image into the canvas (i.e. 2x zoom):

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img,500,500,1000,1000,0,0,1000,1000);
```

In the above, it is saying, extract the area from (500,500) to (1500,1500) and "print" it into the canvas.

Rotation is a little more involved, because if you just `rotate` the image and draw from the origin (0,0) of the canvas, the image will end up off-canvas. You will need to perform a `translate` on the canvas as well.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI/180);    //rotate 90 degrees
ctx.translate(0, -canvas.height); //translate down the height of the canvas
```

OR

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rotate(180 * Math.PI/180);    //rotate 180 degrees
ctx.translate(-canvas.width,-canvas.height);  // translate down and over
```

OR

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rotate(270 * Math.PI/180);    //rotate 270 degrees
ctx.translate(-canvas.width,0);  // translate down and over
```

Note that the rotation occurs around the upper-left corner. It all gets more complex if you want to support free rotation.

Edit: As Blindman67 notes correctly in his comment, the transforms apply to the transformation state of the context based on any prior transformation applied. I updated the code examples to clarify that that is the effect of the transformation when applied to a clean context with no transformation previously applied to it.

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for the answer. Though, now I'm thinking that it will require extra efforts to do. So, I'm removing controls. I liked how to draw smaller image part. I added that. Thanks for quick response. :)

Comment: @KalpeshSingh - :-) - that is understandable. It is a little bit of a pain.

Comment: You fail to mention that rotate, and translate are relative to the existing transformation. The last code segment is completely incorrect, the first rotate and translate are the wrong way around and the following transformations are relative to the existing, the comments do not reflect the actual transformations. I have to down vote because of the errors as it will only confuse people.

Comment: @Blindman67 - thanks for the note - yes, I did forget to mention that. I also see now that my lower code is running together as opposed to three distinct segments. The first 90 degree rotation as a standalone is correct, but the other two would be screwed up. I'll edit to address. Thanks again.